# How to raise a boat up a few blocks

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am creating a boat race course on packed and blue ice. I want the boat to be raised up a block, without lowering its velocity or using commands. I have tried using a tripwire-activated slime block launcher, but it slows the boat down so it comes back on top of the slime block. Will a double launcher work (what I tried already, but with another tripwire above the launcher connected to a horizontal launcher)? If not, what other methods can achieve this?

**Edit:** I tried putting inline tripwire-activated pistons with ice on top, but the timings don't seem right, and fail when multiple boats go over it. Does widening it work, or creating "highway exits" with blockers to raise each boat, then merging these exits?

Comment: Have you tried simply putting pistons in the floor that push the boat up one level?

Comment: Ooh, you could even have sticky pistons under the ice.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Not yet.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to raise boats is using a piston. I have done this when transporting villagers in a boat, so I know it works. If you hook the tripwire to a piston without slime on it, the boat will be raised, and shouldn’t lose speed that way.